# Некорректная работа плагина jquery для стилизации чекбоксов

Tags: jquery, xhtml, javascript, html

Написав плагин для стилизации чекбоксов/радиобаттонов столкнулся с проблемой некорректной работы плагина. Плагин нормально отрабатывает только через один элемент, причем те элементы которые некорректно работают он отрабатывает тоже, только не вешает все нужные события.

Вот демо страница с формой: http://pastehtml.com/view/awf4co19w.html

Вот код самого плагина:

```
jQuery.fn.beautyCheckbox = function(){
    return this.each(function(){
    var checkbox = $(this).filter('[type=checkbox]'); //отсеиваем из всех элементов только чекбоксы
    checkbox.css('display','none');//прячем стандартные чекбоксы
    $('<div class="checkboxImitation"></div>').insertBefore(checkbox);//создаем див, который будет имитировать их работу
    var checkboxImitation = $('div.checkboxImitation');    
    checkboxImitation.addClass('unchecked').hover( //присваиваем класс "не отмеченный" и вешаем события
        function(){
        if($(this).hasClass('checked')){$(this).addClass('checkedHover')}//проверяем в каком состоянии находится элемент и в соответсвии с этим производим манипуляции
        else($(this).addClass('uncheckedHover'))
        },     
        function(){
        if($(this).hasClass('checked')){$(this).removeClass('checkedHover')}
        else($(this).removeClass('uncheckedHover')) }
    ).click(function(){// вешаем событие, которое будет указывать спрятанным чекбоксам их состояние
        if($(this).hasClass('checked')){$(this).removeClass().addClass('checkboxImitation unchecked uncheckedHover');
            $(this).next('input:checkbox').attr('checked',true);
        }
        else{$(this).removeClass().addClass('checkboxImitation checked checkedHover');
            $(this).next('input:checkbox').attr('checked',false);
        }
    });    
    });
}
```

Буду рад любой помощи и советам.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас строчка

```
var checkboxImitation = $('div.checkboxImitation');
```

засасывает все чекбоксы на странице, т. е. с каждой итерацией each их становится на один больше. Обработчик click вы навешиваете на них на все сразу, т. е. там, где он вызывается чётное число раз, кажется, что событие не навешивается.

Попробуйте вот так:

```
var checkboxImitation = $('<div class="checkboxImitation"></div>').insertBefore(checkbox);
```

Comment: Вот эта строчка тоже очень странная:

    var checkbox = $(this).filter('[type=checkbox]'); //отсеиваем из всех элементов только чекбоксы

Тут у вас уже один элемент и вам надо только проверять, чекбокс это или нет (is(), а не filter(). Если не чекбокс, то просто делать return.

Ну и писать $(this) в каждой строчке тоже совсем не по-джедайски.

Comment: замена строчки не особо помогла, и до и после замены количество новых дивов одинаково, но я согласен так правильней. А что касается .filter, то я не согласен зачем запускать еще одну проверку, если можно сразу из полученного элемента отфильтровать чекбокс. Но итог один плагин глючит.

Comment: Надо заменить пятую и шестую строки на эту одну, мне помогло. В вашем коде :)

Про filter(). Проверка в любом случае одна, но смысл разный. И элемент у вас в любом случае один, но он может не быть чекбоксом. В вашем случае вы потом работает с пустым объектом jQuery, а в случае с is, сразу выходите из функции.

Comment: Да получилось,только не могу доделать is: я пишу так if($(this).is('input[type=checkbox]')){ var checkbox = $(this); код плагина далее }else{return false} Но плагин не отрабатывает, как будто ничего не нашел

Comment: Как-то так:


 var checkbox = $(this);
 if (!checkbox.is('input[type=checkbox]')) return;

Comment: да все заработало, спасибо

Answer (score 1):

Артем, большое спасибо, все заработало (тестировал в фф3,6 и ие6). Вот окончательный вариант кода:

```
jQuery.fn.beautyCheckbox = function(){
            return this.each(function(){
            var checkbox = $(this);
            if (!checkbox.is('input[type=checkbox]')) return; //отсеиваем из всех элементов не чекбоксы
            checkbox.css('display','none');//прячем стандартные чекбоксы
            var checkboxImitation = $('<div class="checkboxImitation"></div>').insertBefore(checkbox);
            checkboxImitation.addClass('unchecked').hover( //присваиваем класс "не отмеченный" и вешаем события
                function(){
                if(checkboxImitation.hasClass('checked')){checkboxImitation.addClass('checkedHover')}//проверяем в каком состоянии находится элемент и в соответсвии с этим производим манипуляции
                else(checkboxImitation.addClass('uncheckedHover'))
                },  
                function(){
                if(checkboxImitation.hasClass('checked')){checkboxImitation.removeClass('checkedHover')}
                else(checkboxImitation.removeClass('uncheckedHover')) }
            ).click(function(){// вешаем событие, которое будет указывать спрятанным чекбоксам их состояние
                if(checkboxImitation.hasClass('checked')){checkboxImitation.removeClass().addClass('checkboxImitation unchecked uncheckedHover');
                    checkboxImitation.next('input:checkbox').attr('checked',false);
                }
                else{checkboxImitation.removeClass().addClass('checkboxImitation checked checkedHover');
                    checkboxImitation.next('input:checkbox').attr('checked',true);
                }
            });

            });
            }
```

Answer (score -1):

Попробуйте вешать клик не через `click(function(){})`, a через `live('click', function(){})`.

Comment: не теперь все некорректно работают

Comment: http://pastehtml.com/view/awfra7pkq.html - вынес checkbox из label, задал им разные id.

Comment: да работают, а с чем связан вынос чекбоксов из лейбла, чего лейбл им мешал?

Comment: Ничем не мешал. Просто обычно если указан for, инпут можно и вынести из лейбла. Если инпут внутри, можно for не указывать.

Comment: Почему минусуют не знаю, предложенное решение работает, но тоже как-то через раз, с одной разметкой все нормально с другой формой уже не работает. Не понимаю почему разметка влияет на работу плагина, если с ней взаимодействия нет.